# WP 8.1 WinJS - Get Owner Name

Tags: javascript, html, winjs

How do I get Permission from WP 8.1?

`Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation.nameAccessAllowed` always returns false.

```
Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation.getDisplayNameAsync().done(function (result) {
     // result is always empty
     name = result;
});
```

Comment: it does work well on Win8.1... I have no idea what's going on on WP8.1. Take a look at this working sample for Windows to see if you can spot a difference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.getdisplaynameasync.aspx good luck

Comment: yeah, it does work on Win8.1... but not on WP8.1 for some reason. And thanks, but I already went through that reference with no luck.